# Why .NET cannot manage Unmanaged Memory?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I understand the difference between managed and unmanaged and I also understand how the GC works so please do not tell me about this.

What is puzzling me is when I create and open, let's say, a StreamReader class. Basically .NET does all the work within this wrapper class to open the file etc for me. Since .NET did all the dirty work, why can't it keep track of the resources so it can release them once the StreamReader object is not rooted anymore. In other words, why do we have to implement the Dispose method and release these resources? Why is .NET unable to do this for us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET didn't do all of the dirty work, the dirty work was done in .NET, which isn't quite the same.

Now, `StreamReader` doesn't deal with unmanaged memory or any other unmanaged resources. It does often deal with classes that do have unmanaged resources, though generally stream handles rather than unmanaged memory.

But let's say for sake of example that it does. Let's say it has a the following fields:

```
private IntPtr _chunkOfUnmanagedMemory;
private int _lengthOfUnmanagedMemory;
```

Okay.

> …why can't it keep track of the resources…

It does. There's a `IntPtr` field doing exactly that.

> …so it can release them…

Why should it? Actually, I'll come back to this after…

> …once the StreamReader object is not rooted anymore…

Well, for one thing it wouldn't know it's not rooted any more until after it's scanned to see what objects aren't rooted any more. It's possible to have garbage collection that detects the last reference being released immediately, but that has overhead and it's overhead that must be locked on in multi-threaded scenarios (or worse, potentially multi-threaded scenarios, and just about all heap use is potentially multi-threaded) and still requires some way of handling circular references, as well. So this isn't what .NET does, it doesn't realise the object is unrooted until it needs more memory and tries to see if it can clean up some of what it already has before obtaining more.

So really this has to be "…once it has been **found to** not be rooted…".

Anyway, back to:

> …so it can release them…

Why should it release them? That could mean freeing a chunk of memory that's being used by another process. Not only could it crash the application in question, but it could crash another application that it was communicating with through shared memory. There two things worse than crashing your application, and one of them is crashing another application. The other is crashing the operating system, an that's just about possible this way too (though most OSs today will protect themselves against most such cases).

So .NET needs to not just know that there was a pointer to unmanaged memory (which it does), but also that it is "owned" by the object and should be released, and also how to release it (a wrapper on `GlobalFree`, `HeapFree`, `LocalFree`, `VirtualFree`, `CoTaskMemFree`, `delete`, `free` or a custom memory manager to name just some possibilities on Windows, never mind other OSs, and generally it's not possible to know which of those to call except by knowing how the memory was allocated). It's worse with the sort of case where a class being used with `StreamReader` is actually likely to use in real life, where it could be a handle to a network socket, a file handle, or something else.

Even if we could somehow have code handle all of them, across all the possible types of allocate/release resource across all the OSs, that would still be limited to things that have already been invented, which is not a future-proof limitation to live with.

On the flip-side sometimes you want to aggressively close something that something else might have a reference to. To take your `StreamReader` example, if it was passed the `Stream` from elsewhere you might reach a point where you want to close the stream and force other code that has a reference to it to either detect whether it can be used before attempting, or throw an exception because any further use is a bug: even if we had immediate detection of being rootless that might not be soon enough.

So in all the idea that .NET should release a bunch of stuff willy-nilly doesn't make sense. We need to have a mechanism to say "if this object is being collected (because it's been found to not be rooted any more) and it hasn't already released this resource (because it may have been manually done already) then release it by the following means". And that's exactly what finalisers do.

And since we might not want to wait until that happens, or might want to clean up while we still have a reference, or at the very least might want to avoid slowing up GC by resurrecting objects to go into the finalisation queue, we'd also want a way for the programmer to explicitly call the same clean-up. And that's exactly what `Dispose()` (and in some cases also `Close()`) does.

We'd also want a way to pass that `Dispose()` request through a chain of ownership, which is why in real life though `StreamReader()` doesn't have any unmanaged resources, and hence has no need for a finaliser, it does have a `Dispose()` which calls `Dispose()` on the `Stream` it wraps, unless `LeaveOpen` is true.

Ultimately, if .NET was in fully in charge of something and as such to know if it even **should be** cleaned up, we wouldn't call it "unmanaged", because it would then be managed, by definition.

Comment: Thanks that is a lot of information to absorb. I will need to read this a few times to fully understand it. it is very informative. Can you please suggest some material to read up on this? i have read a lot on GC but it does not cover any of this but I guess it is abstracted for good reasons. please suggest some material, articles or books i can read up for this.

Comment: Also what do you mean "memory share with other applications"; I thought .NET apps get their own memory which is isolated, am I wrong?

Comment: But that's managed memory, which the GC does indeed deal with. Your question asks about unmanaged memory, which is a term for any memory a .NET app got access to not through the normal .NET memory mechanisms. The GC deals solely with managed memory, except for starting finalisers.